# How to automate the run of stored procedure without using SQL Server Agent and SQLCMD?

Tags: sql-server

Our office does not have SQL Server agent installed and when I run SQLCMD command it gave me an error as shown below?

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\c98035>sqlcmd
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native
>   Client 11.0 : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server [2]
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login timeout
>   expired.
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : A
>   network-related or in stance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see  SQL
>   Server Books Online.

Can someone help me to tell me another way or if you can help me fix the error above so I can use SQLCMD.

Comment: Are you running `sqlcmd` on the same host that SQL Server is running on? (I suspect not).

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm sorry for my ignorance. But how can I confirm that?

Comment: Why do you need to run sqlcmd? SQL Agent can run stored procedures directly

Comment: serge - The company does not have SQL Server Agent. I don't see it in the Object explorer. Can you tell me if it's just hidden or something?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using Express. And if you don't know if you are running `sqlcmd` on the same host that SQL Server is installed then (and no offence), it is going to be very difficult to help you. Any further questions are going to be much more complex and if you can't answer that then there's the problem of lack of fundamental knowledge. i would suggest speaking to someone in your office that has knowledge of your server and helping you find the ropes.

Comment: Did you try connecting to the server using the IP address instead of the server name?

Comment: Stop and go read the documentation about sqlcmd. If you do not provide any arguments, the app will attempt to connect to the default instance on the same machine. And now would be a good time to ask questions of the person who installed or manages your companies database server.

Comment: Larnu - I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Management Studio - Enterprise Edition. Should SQL Agent should be included in there? But why it's not appearing in the Object explorer?